# jquery or javascript function after all images loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I am using the `$( window ).load(function()` to fire my action after all images loaded.

But sometimes when a external script or something else need a very long time to load, my functions fire very late even when the images are already loaded.

So I would like to find a function like `$( document ).ready(function()` which waits untill all images loaded and than run my function.
I dont need the whole document to be ready, I just need the images to be loaded for my function.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin make this easy. But you could do it manually buy writing a small script finding all images and tracking their loading and fire a call back when they all are loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's actually fairly easy to do. Image elements have a `complete` flag on them, and they fire `load` or `error` events when they complete. So we can do this *(see note below about the apparent complexity)*:

```
function getAllImagesDonePromise() {
    // A jQuery-style promise we'll resolve
    var d = $.Deferred();

    // Get all images to start with (even complete ones)
    var imgs = $("img");

    // Add a one-time event handler for the load and error events on them
    imgs.one("load.allimages error.allimages", function() {
        // This one completed, remove it
        imgs = imgs.not(this);
        if (imgs.length == 0) {
            // It was the last, resolve
            d.resolve();
        }
    });

    // Find the completed ones
    var complete = imgs.filter(function() { return this.complete; });

    // Remove our handler from completed ones, remove them from our list
    complete.off(".allimages");
    imgs = imgs.not(complete);
    complete = undefined; // Don't need it anymore

    // If none left, resolve; otherwise wait for events
    if (imgs.length == 0) {
        d.resolve();
    }

    // Return the promise for our deferred
    return d.promise();
}
```

And use it like this whenever you need to check:

```
getAllImagesDonePromise().then(function() {
    // They're all done
});
```

You could use it in a script you've put at the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag (or in a `ready` callback if you prefer).

You're probably wondering about the complexity around "complete" images. Why do we hook an event on them, then remove them and unhook the event? It's to deal with race conditions. Although the browser runs the main JavaScript on a single UI thread, the *browser* is *not* single-threaded. It can finish loading an image and set its `complete` property at any time. If we're not already hooked to the `load`/`error` event on that image when that happens, we won't get notification. So if we filtered out completed images first, then hooked the events on the remaining ones, any image that completed *between those lines of code* (again: our code is single-threaded, the browser is not) would never fire the event. So we hook the events, *then* filter out completed ones, then deal with any events we get back.

Comment: @GillesC: Thanks, fixed. :-) (You can fix those directly if you like, that's part of SO's model.)

Comment: Thanks for your nice answear. I get this error: ´TypeError: getAllImagesDonePromise(...) is undefined´. I am calling your function inside a $( document ).ready(function()

Comment: @user3924331: I kinda forgot to put "return d.promise()` at the end. :-)

Comment: Thanks, just perfect!

Comment: great function,, sorry to interupt, but can we use that fn for `background-images` for dom elements somehow?